# How do you search for text without it being converted to a tag name?

Tags: support, search, top-bar

In the top bar search box, how do you do a text search when the word you're searching for is also the name of a tag?

If I type "documentation", for example, it automatically switches it to search for questions tagged [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documentation) rather than leaving it as the word "documentation".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Funnily enough, if you do *actually* search for `"documentation"` (i.e. enclose it in quotes), you will get what you are looking for :)

When quoting, search will use "exact match" and not revert to "is this a tag and if so use it as a tag" logic.